# jquery waypoints hilighting navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-waypoints

I was following a tutorial on creating a single page website with a sticky header using jQuery waypoints.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorials/create-a-sticky-navigation-header-using-jquery-waypoints/

Everything worked fine until I made a little change to my HTML structure.

I placed the navigation under my "about" section which is attached to a waypoint. Under my navigation there's another section which is not attached to a waypoint, since its content still belongs to my "about" section.

Then two other sections attached to waypoints are following.

My sticky function and my scroll function work fine but there's a problem with highlighting the about section since I put my navigation under the section with `id="about"`

I have a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8GENv/

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the following code:

```
var sections = $(".waypointsec");
var navigation_links = $(".navigation .innernav ul li a");

sections.waypoint({
    handler: function(event, direction) {

        var active_section;
        active_section = $(this);
        if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();

        var active_link = $('.navigation .innernav ul li a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');
        navigation_links.removeClass("selected");
        active_link.addClass("selected");

    },
    offset: '60%'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that waypoints can be abit 'clunky' for a sticky nav and the selected states are always abit off, especially with all the different screen size options around.

This plugin is much better and way easier to use and really well documented. It is written with plain old javascript and you can do some really cool stuff with just css!

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

An example might be something like this

```
<div id="something" data-0="position:static;" data-110="position:fixed;top:-110px;left:0;width:100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/skrollr.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ + tablets
(function(a) {
    if(/android|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(ad|hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|meego.+mobile|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino|playbook|silk/i.test(a)
    ||
    /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))
    {
        //Add skrollr mobile on mobile devices.
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/skrollr.mobile.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
</script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/skrollr.ie.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    skrollr.init({
        forceHeight: false
    });
}
</script>
```